# Trouble finding the CDF's of these two pdfs.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am doing a problem for practice and the problems asks to find the cdf for the two pdf's. The first pdf is: 
$$f(x) =  \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x^2} & 1 < x < \infty\\ 0 &\text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$ 
And the second is: 
$$f(x) =  \begin{cases} \frac{1}{3} & 0 < x < 1 & \text{or}& 2<x<4\\ 0 &\text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$
The problem I am having with the first one is that doing the way we doing in class I am unsure of how to deal with the bounds, mainly because we have only ever done finite bounds before, as for the second one I am wondering if I would just add the two bounds in when I write the cdf. Like do it normally then state its such and such for "x in this range or x in this range". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem I am having with the first one is that doing the way we doing in class I am unsure of how to deal with the bounds, mainly because we have only ever done finite bounds before,

Exactly the same principle holds. The distinction is that you only need to consider the intervals below and in the support, as there is no above.

$$F(x) = \begin{cases}0 &:& x\leqslant 0 \\ \displaystyle\int_0^x s^{-2}\mathrm d s & : & 0< x < \infty\end{cases}$$

> as for the second one I am wondering if I would just add the two bounds in when I write the cdf. Like do it normally then state its such and such for "x in this range or x in this range". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Yes, write it as a piecewise function, but here there are **five** pieces to consider: the two pieces of the support, and the intervals, below, between, and above them.

$$\require{enclose}F(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &:& \hspace{4.25ex} x\leqslant 0 \\ \enclose{roundedbox}{\phantom{\int_0^x\tfrac 13\mathrm d s}} &:& 0<x<1 \\ \tfrac 13 & : & 1\leqslant x\leqslant 2 \\ \tfrac 13 +\enclose{roundedbox}{\phantom{ \int_2^s \tfrac 13\mathrm d s}} &:& 2< x< 4 \\ 1 &:& 4\leqslant x  \end{cases}$$